# How to search by category in kentico smartsearch

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

We have added some category at **CMSSiteManager** -> **Administrator** -> **Category**  in admin section.

category as

[image]

we have these categories in site manager's, I have shown these categories on the front end in dropdownlist. Now i want to pass the category id to searchcondition of the kentico cms smart search result. I have used to search the nodeownerfull name.

`SearchCondition = "+(DocumentCreatedByUserID:((int)73 || (int)82))";`

How to search/filter result by these categories on front end using smart search result web parts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to setup the search indexes to index also categories. Go to index settings, then in the dialog where you define, what should be indexed there is a "Include categories" checkbox.

Once you have index which contains category information you can use **DocumentCategories** (contains category labels) or **DocumentCategoryIDs** (contains category IDs) fields of index.

Also see this example [faceted search](http://devnet.kentico.com/Blogs/Jakub-Oczko/August-2012/Kentico-CMS-7-Smart-Search.aspx).